# How to submit all objects from ngFor as an array again?

Tags: angular

I've an JSON from my server application which looks like this one below. I would like to create a form on single page where are all of these values and the user is able to edit them or change on the form. When the user submits the form I would like to send a json to the server which is an array of all of these values as below instead of just submitting one object from the `*ngFor`. Should I use dynamic or reactive forms to achieve it? Any ideas I am new in angular so do not know where to move.

```
values = [
  value1: {
      name: 'Value1',
      value: 'Value depends on the user',
      options: [
          { option: 'Option 1'},
          { option: 'Option 2'},
          { option: 'Option 3'}
      ]
  },
  value2: {
      name: 'Value2',
      value: 'Value depends on the user',
      isEnabled: 'true'
  }
]
```

Comment: If you use `ReactiveForms` you can use method `getRowValue()` and get all form values as an object where the key is control name and value is control value.

Comment: When you submit a form, what is submitted depends on how the form is built. When you say "instead of just submitting one object from the *ngFor", if you have a from which includes the *ngFor, the submit button will submit every items in the *ngFor (since they'll all be linked to your form). But as Kamil says, you will have to use a ReactiveForm and learn how to use it.